# Receiving JSON from AngularJS in Flask

Tags: python, ajax, json, angularjs, flask

I have an AngularJS app, which is sending `HTTP PUT` data to [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/); I can see that the data arrives at the server correctly... however, for some reason, my flask method can't read it when Angular makes an `HTTP PUT` to the server...

*Flask code*:

```python
@app.route('/api/thing/hostform', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def get_blank_host_row():
    retval = [host_row(host_name="RANDOM_HOST")]
    return Response(dumps(retval), mimetype='application/json')

@app.route('/api/thing/hostform', methods=['PUT'])
@login_required
def append_blank_host_row():
    retval = request.form.get('hosts', "!! ERROR !!")
    print "PUT RESULT", retval
    retval.append(host_row())
    return Response(dumps(retval), mimetype='application/json')
```

"formsubmit_add2" correctly GETs from `/api/thing/hostform`; however, for some reason `request.form.get('hosts', "!! ERROR !!")` always errors out with an HTTP 500 error as you can see below...

```
10.93.10.120 - - [11/Apr/2014 13:15:22] "GET /formsubmit_add2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.93.10.120 - - [11/Apr/2014 13:15:22] "GET /api/thing/hostform HTTP/1.1" 200 -
PUT RESULT !! ERROR !!
10.93.10.120 - - [11/Apr/2014 13:15:25] "PUT /api/thing/hostform HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

For anyone who is curious, `request.json` is `None` when I get the `HTTP PUT`...

#### Question

How can I correctly receive what AngularJS is sending to [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)?

---

*Wireshark dump of the HTTP PUT*:

This is a wireshark dump of the HTTP PUT from AngularJS...

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    PUT /api/thing/hostform HTTP/1.1\r\n
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): PUT /api/thing/hostform HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [Message: PUT /api/thing/hostform HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [Severity level: Chat]
            [Group: Sequence]
        Request Method: PUT
        Request URI: /api/thing/hostform
        Request Version: HTTP/1.1
    Host: tsunami:5000\r\n
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0\r\n
    Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n
    Referer: http://server_name:5000/formsubmit_add2\r\n
    Content-Length: 164\r\n
        [Content length: 164]
    Connection: keep-alive\r\n
    \r\n
    [Full request URI: http://server_name:5000/api/thing/hostform]
Line-based text data: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    {"hosts":[{"real_ip_addr":"","switch_port":"","host_nic_role":"Console",
    "host_name":"RANDOM_HOST","host_nic_name":"","switch_name":"",
    "altn_ip_addr":"192.0.2.42"}]}
```

---

*AngularJS $http PUT*:

```javascript
        $scope.add_row = function (data) {
            // build an ajax request with $scope.data
            var send = $http({
                method  : "PUT",
                url     : "/api/thing/hostform",
                headers : {"Content-Type":
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"},
                data: {"hosts": data},
            });
            send.success(
                // something irrelevant here
            );
```

Comment: Why are you sending as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`?

Comment: @astex, using `application/json` fixed the problem... I have successfully communicated otherwise with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in another flask + angular project but something clearly is different here.  Please post that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong mimetype for JSON.  Rather than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, it should be `application/json`.

Answer (score 1):

From the Flask `Request` class documentation:

> **json**
>
> If the mimetype is application/json this will contain the parsed JSON data. Otherwise this will be None.
>
> The get_json() method should be used instead.

I think your problem appears because request.form doesn't contain `hosts` key (contains something else), because your mimetype is not json (application/json).

For a more precise answer please write what comes in `request.form`?

Comment: Regarding what comes in `request.form`, the `hosts` key is there AFAICT... please look at the wireshark output near the bottom of my question.  I will award the accept to astex as soon as he answers, but I should vote this up if you can describe why I couldn't see the `host` key in a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` PUT

Comment: I mean that there is not the format inside `request.form` what do you expect as properly delivered mimetype; if you print it, you'll see it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "if you print it, you'll see it"  `print request.form` is an [`ImmutableMultiDict`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict) werkzeug object

Comment: Yes, but it's keys and values are not what you expect, because of wrong mimetype, so the error occurs. Am I right? :)